# How to check value in the array is present in the array variable or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to achieve a value in the array is present in the array variable or not.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
if (a === 1) {
    alert("green");
}
```

So my goal is to check in the variable `a` holds the value 1 or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `includes`:

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3]

if (a.includes(1))
  console.log('exist');
else
  console.log('not exist');
```

Comment: This is what i want. Thanks Omri

Comment: @SagarSinha although it's a duplicated question, if that's the right answer you should mark it.Good Luck!

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through array members and check if any of the members has that value. Here's an example:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   if(a[i] == 1){
      alert("green");
   }
}
```